# Na pasta java tenho três subpasta, é normal?

Tags: java, xamarin

Estou tendo problema com:

> java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError : java/lang/object.

Já fiz muita coisa que os colegas pediram e nada. Atualizei a PATH e JAVA_HOME e nada. Minha Classpath:

```
;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\htmlconverter.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\rt.jar;
```

Minha PATH do usuário do sistema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Path do Sistema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha JAVA_HOME:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

Minha pasta `C:\Arquivo de programa(x86)\java`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E ainda continuo com o mesmo erro de:

> java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError : java/lang/object

Comment: Existe algum serviço que por ventura esteja desabilitado? Quais os serviços do java para estar rodando?

Comment: Estou desinstalando tudo, apagar as pastas que restarem e reinstalar do zero pra ver se funciona.

Comment: A  última linha da `PATH` do sistema mostra `%JAVA_HOME\bin%`. Não deveria ser `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`?

Comment: Sinceramente, não sabia. Apenas copiei e colei. Vou alterar. Obrigado pela correção.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, fiz a reinstalação e as alterações que o LINQ postou. Não sei se foi a reinstalação ou as alterações, pois quando ele disse, já estava desinstalando. Agora funcionou.